# How do I identify model of my Mikuni carburetor

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, yamaha

I have a 2005 Yamaha 1100 Silverado with a Mikuni carburetor.  5EL540 and  T546 are all I see stamped on the carburetor.

I have been searching for days and don't know what class or model this is. I'ml ooking for a rebuild kit. I need new o-rings and float gasket.

Is there a way to identify the carburetor so I have the ability to order parts for it?

Comment: Here is the part number for your carb.  You can find them all over.  5EL-14900-40-00,    Here is a link a parts explosion w/ part numbers. http://www.yamahapartspro.com/oemparts/a/yam/500453d2f8700209bc7927ee/carburetor   If you have a CA bike there is a different carb part number.  You can find that part # in the link above.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Yamaha part number for your carburetor.  5EL-14900-40-00.

[Here is a link](http://www.yamahapartspro.com/oemparts/a/yam/500453d2f8700209bc7927ee/carburetor) to a parts explosion of your carburetor.

Comment: I gave up and restarted search, thank you very much.